# What is the SoC on the ARM9 board TS-7800?

Tags: embedded, arm, system-on-chip

From [Single Board Computers](http://www.embeddedarm.com/products/arm-sbc.php#ts-7800-500mhz-series)

> The TS-7800 series of single board computers provides 3 times the performance of the TS-7200 series with the same footprint, ***using a Marvell 500MHz ARM9 SoC***.

From [ARM9 TS-7800 Xenomai support](http://www.mail-archive.com/xenomai@xenomai.org/msg00071.html)

> The link you quote provides only very vague information like ***"using a
>   Marvell 500MHz ARM9 SoC" (which can be anything)*** or "use a recent
>   Linux kernel 2.6" (which means they are plain OLD - recent means v3.4
>   or later).  ***This may be sufficient for marketing material, but not for
>   answering technical questions.***

I found [TS-7800 User's Manual](http://oz.embeddedarm.com/~michael/support/ts7800.html). But, I can't find something related to SoC there.

**How do I find out the exact SoC this ARM board uses?**

Comment: I am not an electrical engineering student. Please guide in newbie way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of an old question, but I thought perhaps I could provide some more detailed answers.

The product documentation is currently found here:
http://wiki.embeddedarm.com/wiki/TS-7800

The exact Marvell processor manual is linked on the above wiki, check the right hand side of the page just under the photograph of the SBC.

Unfortunately I lack the reputation to post multiple links, so the above main wiki page link will have to suffice.

You can also email Technologic Systems directly via support@embeddedarm.com, or call them via the telephone number on their web site and just ask for "support".  They are live human people.

Answer (score 2):

The Technologic Systems website you linked-to says [here](http://www.embeddedarm.com/products/board-detail.php?product=TS-7800) that :-

> The TS-7800 is a RoHS compliant Single Board Computer (SBC) based on a Marvell MV88F5182 500MHz ARM9 CPU

Although this processor doesn't seem to be mentioned on Marvell's website (obsolete, perhaps?), Technologic have a PDF manual [here](http://www.embeddedarm.com/documentation/third-party/MV88F5182-usermanual.pdf) (dated 2008) which described the device as a "Feroceon Storage Networking SoC".

The manual isn't a "newbie" guide for non electronic engineers, but as a software developer, you should find it a useful resource.